# create tabular format records from the json in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have list of records which I am iterating in a for loop in jupyter notebook and trying to get the tabular format shown in the image below but since it involves multiple blocks not sure how to do that
I did something like this

```
for record in avro_reader:
            for v in record['features']:
                print (v['id'] , v['xCoordinate'])
```

Here is the json

```
{
   "features":[
      {
         "id":"f1",
         "type":"Node",
         "xCoordinate":"x1",
         "yCoordinate":"y1"
      },
      {
         "id":"f2",
         "type":"Node",
         "xCoordinate":"x2",
         "yCoordinate":"y2"
      }
   ],
   "countries":[
      "A,B"
   ]
}{
   "features":[
      {
         "id":"f3",
         "type":"Node",
         "xCoordinate":"x3",
         "yCoordinate":"y3"
      }
   ],
   "countries":[
      "C"
   ]
}
```

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Are you sure your json data is correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: Your JSON seems to have two root elements. That is not a valid JSON format.

Comment: avro_reader = reader(fo)
    for record in avro_reader:
I read it from avro file which has these records.

Answer (score 1):

On a valid, correct JSON you can do it like this:

```
import json
from json2html import *
from IPython.display import HTML

data = json.loads("YOUR JSON FILE HERE")
HTML(json2html.convert(json = data))
```

For `json2html` library, you can do `pip install json2html`